# vuejs component created wait for data to load first

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have an `App.vue` component where I want to load the currently logged in user. I also want to redirect the user when he\she tries to go the login route and the currently logged in user is already saved in context (he's already signed in).

```
// inside App.vue component
created() {
  AuthService.getCurrentUser().then((user) => {
    this.user = user;
  });
}
```

I have a check in the `created` method of the login component for whether the currentUser is setted, but then when the user tries to go to the login page it might be possible that the the request for the current user is not finished.

**My question is:**

How do I wait for the data to load before the App.vue component loads?
I saw something like this:

```
waitForData: true,
data(transition) {
  return AuthService.getCurrentUser().then(currentUser => {
    transition.next({ currentUser });
  });
}
```

which doesn't actually wait for the data to be loaded and the component loads anyway.

**Edit:** I'm aware of `beforeRouteEnter` but this is `App.vue` component which is a parent component of all components and not a route specific component.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I ran into a very similar problem and solved by adding a **v-if** on the element that wrapped the child component that depends on the loaded data. And then of course have an data property to control that v-if. If you don't have a wrapping element you can always use a [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) element to do the wrapping.

Answer (score 10):

This is not the Vue way of doing things.

1. Use VUEX to store your currentUser object
2. Set up the Vuex getters in App.vue's computed section. Your template will be updated dynamically once the data is ready.

See the mapGetters section in this [page](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).  It works very well with the computed mechanism.

You can also use v-if in your relevant component, so that the component won't be created before your data is ready in VUEX.

Comment: What if the sub-component also needs to fetch data that depends on the parent's data?

Answer (score 4):

If using `vue-router`, you can use the `beforeRouteEnter` guard to load data async, as described here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

Comment: Yes, but this is `App.vue` component for which this doesn't work since it's not attached to any route, or at least I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Nikola maybe use something like `isFetched` state and use v-if to render after state has been fetched?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is when the user is loaed in the `App.vue` component to check the current path and if it's `\login` to redirect.

Something like this:

```
created() {
  AuthService.getCurrentUser()
  .then(user => this.setCurrentUser(user))
  .then(() => {
    const { path } = this.$router.currentRoute;
    if (path === '/login') {
      this.$router.push('/');
    }
  });
```